# SQLite Execute Batch with Connection Commit Java

Tags: java, sql, transactions

I have a question on Java Execute Batch function.

For Example: I have added 10 inserts processes into the batch and I execute the batch. If it fails, with there be some insert process successfully executed and committed? Which means does auto commit happens at any insert processes within the batch? or if one process fails the whole batch inserts will not take place.

Put it into code:

Does the result in here:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
....
statement.addBatch();
....
statement.executeBatch();
....
con.commit();
```

equals to this (IF THE EXECUTE BATCH FAILS!!)

```
....
statement.addBatch();
....
statement.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your batch has failed then all statments of the batch will be rolled back.
It looks like

```
begin transaction
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(1,2) 
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(2,3)
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(3,4) -- fail here
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(4,5)
commit
```

In this case all statments will be rolled back and the first statment and the second.

**UPD1**

When you use auto commit it looks like

```
begin transaction
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(1,2) 
commit
begin transaction
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(2,3)
commit
begin transaction
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(3,4) -- fail here
commit
begin transaction
insert into t1(f1,f2) values(4,5)
commit
```

In this case the first and the second and 4th statments will be commited.

Comment: If that is the case, from many examples on the internet, what is the rationale with setting auto commit to false and then commit after the batch has fully execute if both of my examples above will roll back if one entry fails?